Routing between phone and laptop on wireless LAN not working
I am developing a Flutter app, and I use Firebase Emulator to test my app locally.
In order to be able to test my app on my physical Android phone, I need some way of making my phone communicate with the Emulator, which is running on my laptop.
Both devices are connected to the same wireless network.
Usually what I do is I assign a static IP address to my laptop, and then copy that into my debug run configuration when running the app on my phone, so that the app knows where to find the emulator.
The communication flows as follows: phone <--(WiFi)--> router <--(WiFi)--> laptop.
This usually works fine, but I have moved to a new place with a different network and router and this is not working.
From my laptop, I am able to ping both the laptop itself and my phone by using their local WiFi IP addresses, e.g. 192.168.1.101 and 192.168.1.100, so this tells me that some traffic does make it through from one device to the other via the router.
But the emulator traffic is not working.
For instance, from my laptop I can't access the emulator UI by using the local IP address, as in 192.168.1.101:4000.
The emulator runs on ports 9099 and 8080 on my laptop.
My router is a TP-link model TL-WR1043ND.
What could be going wrong and how can I fix it?
